# Base64 SQL Default Value, Error Validating

Tags: sql-server-2019

I'm trying to insert a base64 image code as the default value for one of my columns. I've tried encapsulating my base64 with single quotes but in SSMS it doesn't show it as a string and am getting errors when trying to save the table.

`-Error validating the default for column 'mycol'`
`-Error modyfing column properties, Unclosed quotation mark after the character string : then shows the entire base64 code.`

I also tried the following way: `(N'(base64here)')` but that also throws the same error.
I did a search/replace in notepad for any other single quotes in my string but there are none.

Not sure whats wrong here? Could it be that the string is too long for an varchar(MAX) field? It's 223210 characters long. I'm using SSMS gui not TSQL to enter the defaul value.

```
(N'(data:image/jpeg;base64,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\=)')
```

The base64 string above is truncated because stackoverflow has character limit btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add it using TSQL

```
ALTER TABLE MYTBL
ADD CONSTRAINT MYCOL
DEFAULT 'base64here' FOR MYCOL;
```